# QT/VLC/Browser differences between flipped video

Tags: video, ffmpeg, vlc

This is a weird one.  I'm converting video from .mov to streaming formats such as .mp4, .ogv, and .webm.  No problems there, using ffmpeg and everything is going fine.

The problem is that when opening the video in VLC, it's the right way up.  When it's converted and viewed in the browser (from the server), it's upside down!

Ok, so I flipped it using the -vf "hflip,vflip" option in ffmpeg.  Uploaded again, and IT'S STILL FLIPPED!  Huh?  I cleared my cache too, no dice.

I'm thinking there must be some flag somewhere that keeps it flipped based on the recording of the movie and the orientation.  Can I remove that somehow?

Comment: I think I found the tag... it's in the metadata of the ffmpeg -i: rotate 180.  Can I remove this somehow?

Comment: I think I solved it!  ffmpeg -i in.mov -f mp4 -metadata rotate="" -vf "hflip,vflip" out.mp4

Comment: You can provide an answer to your own questions too. Also see answer to [iPhone recorded videos getting rotated on Windows systems](http://superuser.com/a/564234/110524).